# How to increase maxReceivedMessageSize

Tags: wcf, stream, config

i have wcf service and i am sending large streams from service to client.

this is my code in client web config

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>

        <binding name="Blabla" allowCookies="true"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
               maxArrayLength="2147483647"
               maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

when i wanted to set maxReceivedMessageSize to more than 2 gb, i get an error. it says "int32 value can not initialize that value". Is it possible to set it to 40 gb or bigger value?

Comment: Not buffered, no.  You might be able to use [WCF Streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx) or [Chunking Channel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717050.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

`maxReceivedMessageSize` can be set to more than `int.MaxValue`, but only if the transfer mode of the binding is set to `Streamed`. You should also not set `maxBufferSize` to 2GB, otherwise you may get a huge memory usage in the client.